# reducing key values of an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like

```
var myArray = [{ques: 1, ans: "A"}, 
               {ques: 2, ans: "D"}, 
               {ques: 3, ans: "C"}];
```

I want to convert it as a new array like:

```
var newArray= [{1: "A"}, {2: "D"}, {3: "C"}]
```

Please help me to achieve it.

**UPDATE**
I have realized that working with newArray is really difficult.OOPS!
it would be meaningful to convert it to

```
var newArray=[1: "A", 2: "D", 3: "C"]
```

Please help me in it.

Comment: That would actually be *harder* to work with. It would be somewhat sensible to reduce it to `{1: "A", 2: "B", 3: "C"}`, but that intermediate is simply the worst of both worlds.

Comment: Why would you want to convert it to objects with inconsistent property names?

Comment: @charlietfl I hv realized it:)

Comment: well that new structure in your update is completely invalid. What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl its just a quiz ,but it has just eaten my minds

Comment: Then this whole question is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4):

`Array.prototype.map()` function should do the job:

```js
var myArray = [{ques: 1, ans: "A"}, {ques: 2, ans: "D"}, {ques: 3, ans: "C"}],
    newArr = myArray.map(function (o) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj[o.ques] = o.ans;
        return newObj;
    });

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function

```
const mappedArr = myArray.map(elem => {
    return {[elem.ques] : elem.ans};
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

```js
var myArray = [{ ques: 1, ans: "A" }, { ques: 2, ans: "D" }, { ques: 3, ans: "C" }], 
    newArray = myArray.map(a => ({ [a.ques]: a.ans }));

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map to transform each element of the array:

```
var myArray = [ {ques: 1, ans: "A"}, 
                {ques: 2, ans: "D"}, 
                {ques: 3, ans: "C"}];

var newArray = myArray.map(function(it) { 
    var ret = {};
    ret[it.ques] = it.ans;
    return ret; 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.